# How to align rotated TextView to the left of RelativeLayout

Tags: android, textview

I have rotated a TextView by 270 degrees. But the problem is that it rotates from the middle point of the x-axis and because of that there is a space at left and right. And because of space, the text can not align at the left of the Relative layout.

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="300dp">
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:text="Sept 2015 - Dec 2016"
      />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> Here is the result.

[image]

> I want to align TextView like this

[image]

Comment: Just a suggestion: try changing the width to something like '12dp'

Comment: It does not solve the problem @KoushikShomChoudhury

Answer (score 2):

View class has setPivotX() and setPivotY() methods which set the point around which the rotation is done. Use these methods to set the convenient rotation point.
The corresponding attributes are android:transformPivotX and android:transformPivotY

Comment: Can you add that to your answer?

Comment: By default, the view rotates around the center of the view. These attributes allow to set the center of rotation. android:transformPivotX="0dp"  android:transformPivotY="0dp" will mean rotation around top left corner of the view.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rediska suggested. I added `android:transformPivotX="0dp"`
It rotated the text but the text was going off the layout. So I had to add a top margin to make it visible. Right now I have added a margin of 100dp. But to make it work with all lengths of TextView. I should first calculate the textView width and then apply it as a top margin.

**The updated code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:text="Sept 2015 - Dec 2016"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:transformPivotX="0dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but in ConstraintLayout. Here is my solution, of course in RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/leftSideTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Left side"
        android:textSize="24sp" />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/rightSideTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Right side"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And code:

```
private fun leftSide() {
    val leftSideText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.leftSideTextView)
    leftSideText.doOnLayout { left ->
        left.rotation = -90f
        val textSize = (left as TextView).textSize
        left.translationX = -left.width / 2.toFloat() + textSize / 2
    }
}

private fun rightSide() {
    val rightSideText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.rightSideTextView)
    rightSideText.doOnLayout { right ->
        right.rotation = 90f
        val textSize = (right as TextView).textSize
        right.translationX = right.width / 2.toFloat() - textSize / 2
    }
}
```

[image]